# Jhipster filtering on default User table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I would like to use filtering functions to select users.

With Jhipster you can enable filtering for exemple by adding `filter <entity>` in order to have additionnal filtering features.

But I don't know how to do that with the default jwt_user. When I use the swagger API I have only these filters : 
[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: JPA filtering code in JHipster is generated only for entities generated by entity generator, it does not work for User and Authority which are created by the application generator. Your only possibility is to add it manually.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks for your answer. I will try to do that manually